# Edge converts search string into URL erroneously

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

**Lots of times** when I type a search string straight into Win10 Edge browser search field or address I got it mistaken with URL and being converted into something unreadable like :

`http://oracle%20providers%20for%20asp.net`

which results in error page.

**Is there a way to fix it or a bug report I can upvote in the Microsoft feedback system?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug... and thankfully this has already been addressed (so there is no need to report it)

The folks on the Windows Insider program have been testing a version of Edge that better handles backslashes and decimal points in the address bar.  So, that pretty much guarantees that this fix will be in the Anniversary Update to Windows 10 that is expected in July.

For future reference:  Please do use the built-in "Send Feedback" tool from within Edge to report (or perhaps upvote) issues like this.